# I want to use only top border line and right and left top corners . I did it but corners colors does not appear. Can anybody help me?

Tags: ios, swift, border, rounded-corners

extension UIView {
func roundCorners(view :UIView, corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath
view.layer.mask = mask
path.close()
let color = UIColor.white
color.setStroke()
path.stroke()

```
}


enum ViewSide: String {
        case Left = "Left", Right = "Right", Top = "Top", Bottom = "Bottom"
    }
func addBorder(toSide side: ViewSide, withColor color: CGColor, andThickness thickness: CGFloat) {
        
        let border = CALayer()
        border.borderColor = color
        border.name = side.rawValue
        switch side {
        case .Left: border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
        case .Right: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
        case .Top: border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
        case .Bottom: border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - thickness, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
        }
        
        border.borderWidth = thickness
        
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
    
    func removeBorder(toSide side: ViewSide) {
        guard let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers else { return }
        var layerForRemove: CALayer?
        for layer in sublayers {
            if layer.name == side.rawValue {
                layerForRemove = layer
            }
        }
        if let layer = layerForRemove {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TabbarView: UIView {
    var viewColor = UIView()

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        addBorder(toSide: .Bottom, withColor:CGColor.init(gray: 100/255, alpha: 100/255), andThickness: 1)
        addBorder(toSide: .Top, withColor: CGColor.init(gray: 100/255, alpha: 100/255), andThickness: 1)
        addBorder(toSide: .Left, withColor: CGColor.init(gray: 100/255, alpha: 100/255), andThickness: 1)
        addBorder(toSide: .Right, withColor: CGColor.init(gray: 100/255, alpha: 100/255), andThickness: 1)
        self.roundCorners(view: self, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)

        removeBorder(toSide: .Bottom)
        removeBorder(toSide: .Left)
        removeBorder(toSide: .Right)
}
```